# SQL Timeout with dotnet core in Docker when getting somewhat larger than usual DB results from local SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, docker, .net-core

We are developing a .NET Core project in Docker for Windows and we need to retrieve the list of countries (~250records) with about 9 additional columns, which are not longer than guids. While developing, each developer is using a local instance of Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Developer edition.

The problem is, when selecting these ~250 records, some new and powerful workstations have no problem (although this implies they might have problems for larger queries). However, some weaker and older laptops cannot execute the query, and SQL Server throws a timeout. We thought this was a RAM problem, and increased the RAM of the laptops, but issue is not resolved.

The odd thing is that there is a record count threshold which the timeout is thrown. I don't remember the exact number for each laptop, but let's say 120. When number of records is 120 then the query is returned successfully in about 2-3 seconds. However once the number of queries become 121, the timeout exception is thrown. And there is no issue when we use a remote SQL Server, although that server is a VM sharing the host with 6 other VMs and works fairly slow when connected via SQL Server Management Studio. Similarly, managing the local server with SQL Server Management Studio is fast, and the very same query executes in about 1 second.

What could be the problem with this behavior? Is there somehow a limit on Docker's TCP when communicating with the host?

**Edit:** Adding the part of code that i retrieve the records:

```
 public List<CountryDTO> Get(FilterParameters filterParameters)
    {
        IQueryable<Country> query = dbContext.Countries.OrderBy(w => w.Name);

        //...Some basic filtering code, but does not execute since filter is empty
        var entityList = query.ToList();
        return Mapper.Map<List<CountryDTO>>(entityList);
    }
```

Comment: This sounds more like a DB/query design problem than Docker. How complex is the query? Stored procedure or statement? Can you share your [relevant] DB design and query?

Comment: Well the statement is not complex at all. Though I am using dotnet EF to access the DB, might be a good idea to investigate the load that creates. I added the relevant code in the question.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem, or at least a similar one. `SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader` fails if the SQL statement tries to fetch "too many" columns from a single row using a simple `SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN ... WHERE ...`, whether by stored procedure or not. If I run the project directly outside docker, everything works fine.

Comment: I posted an issue [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37621), hoping it leads somewhere.

Comment: @brandon-Barnett, only 250 records with 9 additional columns.no matter how poor query/code or index is.Yes in case small table is join with large table then it may show connection timeout problem. I will suggest  to create TestMethod which contain very  simple code and query like select * from countrytable.

Comment: since the new powerful laptops could `have problems for larger queries` I would say it's more like the database itself has issues (architecture, queries, indexes ..etc), or your actual code (app) have a poor structure or wrong methods (like using scalar query when you need reader, and using reader while you need adapter .. so on. You need to solve it first and make sure the new laptops can handle larger queries or even much complex once. Then, you can go back to the old laptops and it might be solved as well.

Comment: You mentioned that SQL Server throws a timeout but, to be clear, it is the client API that is throwing the timeout error. SQL Server will happily execute a query forever. I would focus on network. It seems the result set size may be a factor where results requiring more than one round trip on the slower clients experience the problem. Try a Wire Shark or similar trace.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. My first query succeeds but the second query fails. Did you have any luck fixing this issue?

Comment: @E. Mourits, unfortunately I don't remember exactly what we did, or if we did anything at all :( Could be resolved after an update.

Answer (score 0):

in your case , you are facing at least 3 matter which must be checked

1.script you are using (you can execute script directly in your sql and check duration of executing, if have to get exact script which your program send it to the sql (for this you can run sql profiler and run your software to get it))

2. network latency (if your software and your db are in different servers), you can yous wire shark for transferring data between 2 servers and see how many latency are you have

3.casting result from your db to software object (you can handle that with diagnosis tools such as jetBrain)

after detecting your problem state you can going to further step

Please tell me when you are sure that the problem is for what stage,i can tell you some solutions

Comment: SQL runs just fine, even when the query is executed from within container, the SQL profiler states that it is completed successfully, so it looks like packets are lost at somewhere inside the connection.
2. Wireshark is a good idea, I hope it can watch the docker network, i'll try it. 
3. Checked that it is not a problem.

Comment: you have to turn on traces for long duration and blocked and dead locks and performance counter(memory usage and cpu usage) too to check what happen in some of your laptops, if you have multiple connection to sql server you can helped by sql logging process which logs everything

Answer (score 0):

As this seems to be a problem specifically with local docker instance and not a SQL Server problem, I am suggesting below steps to handle this issue.

1. Vertically partition the country table into two or more tables, based on the normalization or based on the access pattern of the columns (frequently used columns and rarely used columns). Refer [Normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) & Refer [Vertical Partitioning](http://aboutsqlserver.com/2010/09/15/vertical-partitioning-as-the-way-to-reduce-io/)
2. Query these vertically partitioned tables separately and join them inside .net code and apply filters accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the input. These solutions are doable, however it would severely impact our development if the problem persists. Because it is unpredictable and could occur at any other time, say, while trying to get a smaller table for instance.